# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^6+5a^5b)\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^6}{27}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers. Prove that:
$$4(a^6+b^6+c^6)+5(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^6}{27}$$
I tried SOS, uvw and more, but without success.

Comment: What is SOS and uvw ?

Comment: @user230452 See here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h80127 and here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Answer (score 1):

The following proof is true if they are non-negative reals.

$4(x^3+y^3+z^3)+15xyz\geq (x+y+z)^3$- this directly follows from Schur. So $$4(a^6+b^6+b^6)+5(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)\geq 4(a^6+b^6+c^6)+15a^2b^2c^2\geq (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq\dfrac{(a+b+c)^6}{27}$$

Comment: Nice. But can you explain the first inequality ? How to prove $a^5b + b^5c +c^5a \geq 3a^2b^2c^2$ ? Thanks.

Comment: it is AM-GM: $x+y+z\geq 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$

Comment: @dezdichado Your inequality $x+y+z\geq3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ and your solution are wrong! Try $x=y=0$ and $z=-1$.

Comment: I see, they can be negative.

Comment: @dezdichado OMG. You're right, it's so obvious. I missed it.

Comment: @user230452 Do you mean that the solution of  dezdichado is obviously wrong? What have you missed?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I meant the proof of $a^5b + b^5c + c^5a \geq 3a^2b^2c^2$. I missed that. There's no need to be so rude.

Comment: @user230452 2 It's wrong! Try $c=0$, $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You're right,

Answer (score 1):

With computer, here is a solution.

We have
$$4(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 5(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) - \frac{(a+b+c)^6}{27} = \frac{1}{324}z^TQz$$
where
\begin{align}
z = \left(\begin{array}{l} a^2\, b - a^3\\ a^2\, c - a^3\\ a^3 - 2\, a^2\, b + a\, b^2\\ a^3 - a^2\, c - a^2\, b + a\, b\, c\\ a^3 - 2\, a^2\, c + a\, c^2\\  - a^3 + 3\, a^2\, b - 3\, a\, b^2 + b^3\\  - a^3 + 2\, a^2\, b + c\, a^2 - a\, b^2 - 2\, c\, a\, b + c\, b^2\\  - a^3 + 2\, a^2\, c + b\, a^2 - a\, c^2 - 2\, b\, a\, c + b\, c^2\\  - a^3 + 3\, a^2\, c - 3\, a\, c^2 + c^3 \end{array}\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
Q = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 21060 & -10530 & 17820 & 4515 & -8817 & 3685 & 4023 & -1722 & -1575\\ -10530 & 21060 & -6135 & -903 & 17820 & -882 & -2166 & 1785 & 3783\\ 17820 & -6135 & 18550 & 1719 & -4026 & 4590 & 3570 & -2286 & -285\\ 4515 & -903 & 1719 & 6108 & -3450 & -60 & 1485 & 1320 & -1332\\ -8817 & 17820 & -4026 & -3450 & 18354 & -279 & -2115 & 792 & 4590\\ 3685 & -882 & 4590 & -60 & -279 & 1284 & 774 & -642 & 126\\ 4023 & -2166 & 3570 & 1485 & -2115 & 774 & 1104 & -246 & -485\\ -1722 & 1785 & -2286 & 1320 & 792 & -642 & -246 & 790 & -36\\ -1575 & 3783 & -285 & -1332 & 4590 & 126 & -485 & -36 & 1284 \end{array}\right).
\end{align}
It is easy to verify that $Q$ is (real symmetric) positive definite. We are done.

Comment: It's very hard!

Comment: @knvy144444  Q is $9\times 9$ which is small. In some problems, $Q$ may be large which makes it difficult to find SOS.

Comment: I agree. But how do you get Q in Maple?

Comment: I did not use maple to get SOS. I used matlab.

Comment: Wow, so what tool you use in Matlab?

Comment: See my comments: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239243/an-inequality-concerning-lagranges-identity/335440#335440

Comment: @lsxpqr See my last comment.