# Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+bc+c^2+3}+\frac{c}{c^2+ca+a^2+3}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$

I think this inequality is very interesting because most of the contest's inequalities are homogeneous, 
but this inequality is non-homogeneous.

Testing for $c=0$ gives
$$\frac{a}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}+\frac{b}{b^2+3}\leq0.455...<\frac{1}{2}.$$
For $b=c=0$ we obtain something obvious.

One of the standard ways to prove these inequalities is to try to make a homogenization.

By the way, trying of homogenization gives a wrong inequality:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\leq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{2\sqrt{3(a^2+ab+b^2}}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{3(a^2+ab+b^2)}}\leq1,$$
which is wrong for $c=0$ and $a\rightarrow+\infty$.

Also we can try the following.

We know that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+y}\le1$ for positives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, by C-S we obtain:
$$1-\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+y}=1-\frac{3}{2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{2x+y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{y}{2x+y}-\frac{1}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{2xy+y^2}-\frac{1}{2}\geq\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2+2xy)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$a^2+ab+b^2+3\geq2(2a+\sqrt{ab})$$ 
because if it's true so 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2(2a+\sqrt{ab})}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
But the inequality $a^2+ab+b^2+3\geq2(2a+\sqrt{ab})$ is wrong! Try $a=2$ and $b=\frac{1}{4}$

Also we can try to use a full expanding (I tried!) and to hope to use AM-GM,

but I think this way is very ugly and it's probably nothing.

Any hint would be desirable.

Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain me, why we see two persons, which want to close this topic? Thank you! Can this person (which want to close) explain me, why you do it?

Comment: Hello Michael I have a very simple proof for all the cases except $a,b,c\geq 1$.My question is have you a proof in this case ?

Comment: I did not think about this because I am looking for a full solution.

Comment: Okay no problem Can I pick up some of your ideas ?

Comment: A full expanding gives something interesting, but I still don't see how to end the proof.

Comment: I'm going to try this thanks a lot .

Comment: @FatsWallers You say above that you have a proof for all cases except $a,b,c \ge 1$. That's great, because I have a proof only for the case $a,b,c \ge 1$. Why don't you post yours, I post mine, and we got it done?

Comment: @FatsWallers I have posted my partial proof now. Can you post yours?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you tell me if there is mistake in my proof ?

Comment: The inequality is true for all real numbers.

Comment: Also I have a proof using Sum of Squares (SOS) similar to my solution for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063091/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc4a65a5b-geq-fracabc627/3346098#3346098

Comment: @River Li It seems that I found a proof by BW, but three days ago my WF stopped to help me and I can not check my proof now. :(

Comment: Nice. Hope to see it.

Comment: @River Li I restored my post. See now.

Comment: Is there many equality cases? I can only found $a=b=c=1$

Comment: @knvy144444 I think $a=b=c=1$ only.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get something :

> Lemma

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto\mathbb{R^+}$ a real convex function for all $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ positive real numbers then :
$$\frac{f(a)}{f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3}+\frac{f(b)}{f(b)^2+f(b)f(c)+f(c)^2+3}+\frac{f(c)}{f(c)^2+f(c)f(a)+f(a)^2+3}\leq\frac{f(a)+\alpha f(b)}{\alpha(f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3)}+\frac{f(b)+\beta f(c)}{\beta(f(b)^2+f(b)f(c)+f(c)^2+3)}+\frac{f(c)+\gamma f(a)}{\gamma(f(c)^2+f(c)f(a)+f(a)^2+3)}$$

> Proof :

If we compare this :
$$\frac{f(a)}{f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3}\leq \frac{f(a)+\alpha f(b)}{\alpha(f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3)}\quad(1)$$

We get :

$$0\leq \alpha f(b)+(1-\alpha) f(a)$$

But with the definition of convexity we get :

$$0\leq f( (\alpha) (b)+(1-\alpha)(a))\leq\alpha f(b)+(1-\alpha) f(a)$$

So the inequality (1) is true , and sum to get the lemma .

Now put $\alpha=\frac{1}{2f(a)}$$\quad $$\beta=\frac{1}{2f(b)}$$\quad $$\gamma=\frac{1}{2f(c)}$

We get :

$$\frac{f(a)}{f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3}+\frac{f(b)}{f(b)^2+f(b)f(c)+f(c)^2+3}+\frac{f(c)}{f(c)^2+f(c)f(a)+f(a)^2+3}\leq\frac{0.5+2f(a) f(b)}{(f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3)}+\frac{0.5+f(b) f(c)}{(f(b)^2+f(b)f(c)+f(c)^2+3)}+\frac{0.5+f(c)f(a)}{(f(c)^2+f(c)f(a)+f(a)^2+3)}$$

But the minimum of :
$$\frac{0.5+2f(a) f(b)}{(f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3)}$$ is reached when $f(a)=f(b)=0$

So we get :

$$\frac{f(a)}{f(a)^2+f(a)f(b)+f(b)^2+3}+\frac{f(b)}{f(b)^2+f(b)f(c)+f(c)^2+3}+\frac{f(c)}{f(c)^2+f(c)f(a)+f(a)^2+3}\leq 0.5$$

Done !

Comment: "the minimum of" occurs for $a=b=c=0$, but in the starting inequality the maximum occurs for $a=b=c=1$, which says that your last step is wrong.

Comment: Now it would be correct dear Michael .

Comment: Why the maximum is $2$? We need to prove it.

Comment: I edit what do you think about dear Michael ?

Comment: Why the first inequality is true? Your second inequality is obviously wrong. Try $b\rightarrow0^+$.

Answer (score 0):

** Partial result **

OK - as  announced in the comments, I hope that @FatsWallers will post his  proof for all cases except $a,b,c≥1$ (he said he has one). That would be  great, because I have a proof only for the case $a,b,c≥1$ which I post here. It's rather straightforward.

In the original question, resubstitute $a \to 1+a$, $b \to 1+b$, $c \to 1+c$.

From the original $a,b,c≥1$ (the case I wish to prove), you have now $a,b,c\geq 0$ and you need to show

$$
\frac12 -  \sum_{cyclic}\frac{1+a}{a^2 + a b + 3 a + b^2 + 3 b + 6}  \geq 0
$$

Full expansion (with the usual help of Wolframalpha) gives

$$
 \frac{N}{2 (a^2 + a b + 3 a + b^2 + 3 b + 6) (a^2 + a c + 3 a + c^2 + 3 c + 6) (b^2 + b c + 3 b + c^2 + 3 c + 6)} \geq 0
$$

with

$$
 N = a^4 b^2 + a^4 b c + a^4 b + a^4 c^2 + 3 a^4 c + 4 a^4 + a^3 b^3 + 2 a^3 b^2 c + 5 a^3 b^2 + 2 a^3 b c^2 + 8 a^3 b c + 4 a^3 b + a^3 c^3 + 7 a^3 c^2 + 16 a^3 c + 12 a^3 + a^2 b^4 + 2 a^2 b^3 c + 7 a^2 b^3 + 3 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 12 a^2 b^2 c + 21 a^2 b^2 + 2 a^2 b c^3 + 12 a^2 b c^2 + 27 a^2 b c + 15 a^2 b + a^2 c^4 + 5 a^2 c^3 + 21 a^2 c^2 + 33 a^2 c + 24 a^2 + a b^4 c + 3 a b^4 + 2 a b^3 c^2 + 8 a b^3 c + 16 a b^3 + 2 a b^2 c^3 + 12 a b^2 c^2 + 27 a b^2 c + 33 a b^2 + a b c^4 + 8 a b c^3 + 27 a b c^2 + 36 a b c + 12 a b + a c^4 + 4 a c^3 + 15 a c^2 + 12 a c + b^4 c^2 + b^4 c + 4 b^4 + b^3 c^3 + 5 b^3 c^2 + 4 b^3 c + 12 b^3 + b^2 c^4 + 7 b^2 c^3 + 21 b^2 c^2 + 15 b^2 c + 24 b^2 + 3 b c^4 + 16 b c^3 + 33 b c^2 + 12 b c + 4 c^4 + 12 c^3 + 24 c^2 \geq 0
$$

to be established.  Since $a,b,c\geq 0$, we are done, since all terms are nonnegative.

Remaining cases (not $a,b,c\geq 0$): waiting for @FatsWallers announced  proof.

Answer (score 0):

After full expanding we need to prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)-2\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+2a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+3a^2b^2c)+$$
$$+3\sum_{cyc}(a^4+a^3b+a^3c+3a^2b^2+3a^2bc)-6\sum_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+abc)+$$
$$+9\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)-18(a+b+c)+27\geq0.$$
We'll prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)+\frac{4}{3}(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)+5\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq$$
$$\geq2\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+2a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+3a^2b^2c).$$
Indeed, by AM-GM
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)+\frac{4}{3}(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)+5\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)\left(\frac{4}{3}(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)+5\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\right)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove here that
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+ab+b^2)\left(\frac{4}{3}(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)+5\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+2a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+3a^2b^2c)\right)^2.$$
Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, the last inequality it's $P\geq0$, where $P$ a polynomial degree $8$ of $a$ with non-negative coefficients.

Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{5}{3}a^4+\frac{5}{3}a^3b+\frac{5}{3}a^3c+4a^2b^2+9a^2bc\right)-6\sum_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+abc)+$$
$$+9\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)-18(a+b+c)+27\geq0.$$
Now, we'll prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{5}{3}a^4+\frac{5}{3}a^3b+\frac{5}{3}a^3c+4a^2b^2+9a^2bc\right)-6\sum_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+abc)+$$
$$+6\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)\geq0.$$
Indeed, by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{5}{3}a^4+\frac{5}{3}a^3b+\frac{5}{3}a^3c+4a^2b^2+9a^2bc\right)+6\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{2\sum_{cyc}\left(5a^4+5a^3b+5a^3c+12a^2b^2+27a^2bc\right)\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)}$$ and it's enough to prove here that
$$2\sum_{cyc}\left(5a^4+5a^3b+5a^3c+12a^2b^2+27a^2bc\right)\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)\geq$$
$$\geq9\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+abc)\right)^2.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove here that
$$2(5(27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3)\cdot3u+12(9v^4-6uw^3)+81uw^3)(2(9u^2-6v^2)+3v^2)\geq$$
$$\geq9\left(27u^3-27uv^2+2(9uv^2-3w^3)+3w^3\right)^2$$ or 
$$2(2u^2-v^2)(15u^4-15u^2v^2+4v^4+2uw^3)\geq3(3u^3-uv^2)^2,$$
which is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$, which happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Since the last inequality is homogeneous and symmetric, we can assume $c=0$ and $b=1$, which gives
$$2(5a^4+5+5a^3+5a+12a^2)(2a^2+2+a)\geq9(a^3+1+2a^2+2a)^2.$$
Now, let $a^2+1=2ta$.

Thus, by AM-GM $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$2(5(4t^2-2)+5\cdot2t+12)(4t+1)\geq9(a+1)^2(a^2+a+1)^2$$ or
$$2(4t+1)(10t^2+5t+1)\geq9(t+1)(2t+1)^2,$$ 
which is wrong :(

Comment: @River Li  I think we can fix a last inequality such that it would be true (for example we can take a coefficient is less than $\frac{4}{3}$). Also, maybe the inequality after words "Id est, it's enough to prove" is true already, but I can not  check it now.

Comment: So, you reduced the inequality to the first inequality after "Id est"? It is true for all real numbers.