# Clarification about a proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, fractions, jensen-inequality

it's just a clarification about a proof :

The starting inequality is :

$$0.5\geq1.5-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}+1}$$

So we study the function $f(x)=0.5-\frac{1}{x+1}$ wich is concave so we can apply Jensen inequality we get :
$$0.5-\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}}}{3}+1}\geq\frac{1}{3}(1.5-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}+1})$$

Wich is equivalent to :

$$1.5-\frac{3}{\frac{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}}}{3}+1}\geq(1.5-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}+1})$$

But it's easy to find the minimum of :

$$\frac{3}{\frac{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}}}{3}+1}$$

Wich is one so we have :

$$0.5\geq 1.5-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+1}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}+1}$$

Done !

But Michael Rozenberg says that there is a mistake but I don't see where .

Edit : It's related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178346/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa2abb23-leq-frac12)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this related to another post? you might like to include that link in your post if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}+1}\geq\frac{3}{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}}{3}+1}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\geq\frac{18}{\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}+3}.$$

Now, you want to use the following reasoning.

Since $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}=3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}-1\right)=$$
$$=3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{4a}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}\geq3,$$
where the equality occurs for $a=b=c=0$, we see that the minimal value of 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab+2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}$$ is $3$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\geq\frac{18}{3+3}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+ab-2a+b^2+3}{a^2+ab+b^2+3}\geq3$$ and here you say that the starting inequality is proven.

I think it's not so because the last inequality is wrong.

Try $a=b=c=1$.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes it's very clear , thanks you very much .

Comment: Michael Rozenberg, congratulation for your silver tag [proof-verification]. Hope you success in your next milestones!