# Prove that $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (40a^6 + 53a^5b) \ge 0$

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method

(P1) Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers. Prove that $40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge 0.$

This inequality is verified by Mathematica. I am particularly interested in (simple) SOS solutions (also for (P2) and (P3) below),
however, any comments and solutions are welcome. I also gave a SOS solution for (P2) below, but it is complicated.

Some relevant questions:

(P2) Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers. Prove that $4(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 5(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^6}{27}.$

[Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^6+5a^5b)\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^6}{27}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063091/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc4a65a5b-geq-fracabc627?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(P3) Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers. Prove that $4(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 5(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)^3}{8}.$

[Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(4x^6+5x^5y)\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+xy)\right)^3}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192073/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc4x65x5y-geq-frac-left-sum-limits-cycx2x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha can't put the best $constant$ , but Mathematica (I used discriminant to find this inequality https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138409/685744).

Comment: A big problem around $(a,b,c)=(1.05,-0.62,-1.15)$ for which the left side is closed to $0.111...$.

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh  Thanks. How is this question related to that question?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  I think that we may prove something like your inequality $40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge k (a+b+c)^6$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: @River Li It seems that it's true for $k=\frac{31}{81}$, but I have no a proof.At least, now we can write this inequality in the SOS's  form.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, you are right which can be verified by Mathematica.

Comment: I've the SOS form for all the problem but very very ugly.

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG  All the problems?

Comment: For all P1, P2, P3

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG Are they very long?

Comment: Yes, it's very very long

Comment: Sometimes, one may easily express it as $u^\mathsf{T}Q u$ where $Q$ is constant symmetric rational matrix
and $u$ is a vector containing monomials in variables. If you can do it, what is the size of $Q$?

Comment: I use my tool to run on Maple, example see [P2 SOS](https://pastebin.com/sguM1Wym)

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag It is amazing! How powerful is it? Did you try complicated SOS? You may try my another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711967/sum-of-squares-sos-solutions-for-a2b2c2d2abcd1-ge-abbccdda-acb

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag  By the way, for P2, I have posted one SOS solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063091/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc4a65a5b-geq-fracabc627?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: My tool check this, $k_{\max} = \frac{31}{81}$ for the inequality $40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge k (a+b+c)^6.$ https://i.imgur.com/TO4yJbI.png

Comment: @tthnew  Very nice. So $\frac{40(a^6 + b^6 + c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a)}{(a+b+c)^6}$ achieves its minimum at $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: @RiverLi I can't not get SOS. It's very hard for me. But I can check inequality.

Comment: @tthnew  I cannot get SOS.

Comment: Yes, I mean I can't get SOS. Thanks.

Comment: @tthnew  I am not correcting your spelling. I cannot get SOS currently.

Comment: @RiverLi Ok, my SOS is not true for all reals, it's only true when $a=b=c.$ https://i.imgur.com/eYQIc3p.png

Comment: @tthnew  Nice. By the way, for $a, b, c\ge 0$, it is easy to prove the inequality by BW. So, if $a \ge b \ge c$, we get SOS, and for $b\ge a\ge c$, we get SOS. But your SOS is better.

Comment: How do you get SOS from BW?

Comment: For $a \ge b \ge c$, let $b=c+s, a = c+s+t$ for $s, t \ge 0$ and we have $f(a,b,c)$ is a polynomial in $s, t$ with non-negative coefficients. Since $s = b - c, t = a-b$, we have $f(a,b,c) = (35720/9)*c*(b-c)^3*(a-b)^2 + \cdots$. It is not a standard SOS. Your SOS is standard.

Comment: @nguyenhuyenag Could you give me P1, P3 SOS? I can't not do it by SOS.

Comment: @RiverLi I can give SOS for $40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge \dfrac{31}{81}(a+b+c)^6$ but the coefficients is very very very and very big!

Answer (score 1):

My P2 SOS is ugly, the coefficients is too large, I will try to improve my tool:

We have:

$$27\left[4\left(a^6+b^6+c^6\right)+5\left(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a\right)\right]-(a+b+c)^6$$

$$={\frac {1}{418495910519665315875436}}{c}^{2} \left( 1877899493539b +2231128254114c \right) ^{2} \left( b-c \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{1227564566709386794764}}\left( b-c \right) ^{2} \left( 111426599762{b}^{2}+57572325931bc-66554368268{c}^{2} \right) ^{2 }$$

$$+{\frac {1}{4982400602455205424}}\left( 11016800022a{c}^{2}- 8322034448{b}^{3}-16516031087{b}^{2}c+953764263b{c}^{2}+ 12867501250{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{110170254068928}}\left( 41114072abc-13516246\,a{c}^{2} -63487932{b}^{3}-24871895{b}^{2}c+68571471b{c}^{2}-7809470{c}^ {3} \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{92668107698496}} \left( 58951728a{b}^{2}+20957464abc- 61903346a{c}^{2}+23285292{b}^{3}+20567219{b}^{2}c-22826379b{c} ^{2}-39031978{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{145642643664}}\left( 3143864{a}^{2}c-684660a{b}^{2}+ 1346196abc-252458\,a{c}^{2}-539136{b}^{3}-876131{b}^{2}c+54651b{c}^{2}-2192326{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{9913764}}\left( 23163{a}^{2}b+6338{a}^{2}c+11364a{ b}^{2}+3372abc-5897a{c}^{2}-19512{b}^{3}-9398{b}^{2}c-2028b{ c}^{2}-7402{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}$$

$$+{\frac {1}{428}} \left( 214{a}^{3}+129{a}^{2}b-6{a}^{2}c-108a{b}^{2}-56abc-87a{c}^{2}-8{b}^{3}-30{b}^{2}c-44b{c}^{2}-4 {c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+{\frac {5083151117301}{1877899493539}}{c}^{4} \left( b-c \right) ^{2}\ge 0,$$

which give us qed./

See also [here.](https://t-t-h-n-e-w.blogspot.com/2021/02/2521.html)

Comment: It is nice. In matrix form, it may be not very large.

Comment: @RiverLi SOStools of Matlab can't not give us this exact form, right. For P1 is very very ...large.

Comment: Yes, for small degree and small numbers of variables, the integers in rational SOS can be huge (> 100digits).

Comment: @RiverLi I send you something in AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

Since the exact SOS for the stronger problem of P1 is very very big, can not express in $\LaTeX;$

So here I only give the approximate SOS for
$$40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) \ge \dfrac{31}{81}(a+b+c)^6$$

Have

$$40(a^6+b^6+c^6) + 53(a^5b+b^5c+c^5a) - \dfrac{31}{81}(a+b+c)^6$$

$$\approx 39.62\, \left( {a}^{3}+ 0.6399\,{a}^{2}b- 0.02898\,{a}^{2}c- 0.5041\,
a{b}^{2}- 0.3277\,abc- 0.4398\,a{c}^{2}+ 0.04222\,{b}^{3}- 0.08519\,{b
}^{2}c- 0.2490\,b{c}^{2}- 0.04745\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}$$
$$+ 25.53\,
 \left( {a}^{2}c- 0.2476a{b}^{2}+ 0.4192abc- 0.04827a{c}^{2}-
 0.1957\,{b}^{3}- 0.3349{b}^{2}c+ 0.03937b{c}^{2}- 0.6321{c}^{3}
 \right) ^{2}+ 17.98\left( {a}^{2}b+ 0.4437{a}^{2}c+ 0.4049a{b}
^{2}+ 0.1510\,abc- 0.1529\,a{c}^{2}- 0.8971\,{b}^{3}- 0.3941\,{b}^{2}c
- 0.08513\,b{c}^{2}- 0.4704\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+ 9.789\, \left( a{b}
^{2}+ 0.5075\,abc- 1.492\,a{c}^{2}+ 0.5095\,{b}^{3}+ 0.7374\,{b}^{2}c-
 0.2611\,b{c}^{2}- 1.001\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+ 6.027\, \left( abc+
 0.03308\,a{c}^{2}- 1.885\,{b}^{3}- 1.121\,{b}^{2}c+ 1.783\,b{c}^{2}+
 0.1908\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+ 3.993\, \left( a{c}^{2}- 0.1356\,{b}^{3
}- 2.018\,{b}^{2}c- 0.7975\,b{c}^{2}+ 1.951\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+
 0.06508\, \left( {b}^{3}- 0.6985\,{b}^{2}c- 1.349\,b{c}^{2}+ 1.047\,{
c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+ 0.03708\, \left( {b}^{2}c- 0.03128\,b{c}^{2}-
 0.9687\,{c}^{3} \right) ^{2}+ 0.005711\, \left( b{c}^{2}- 1.0\,{c}^{3
} \right) ^{2}\ge 0,$$

which is obvious.

If you want to see the exact SOS, please visit [Github](https://github.com/tthnew/raw/blob/master/P.1a.sos.2521.java).