# Prove $( xy+2x+2y+1 ) ^{2} ( x+y+2 ) ^{2}\geqslant \frac14 [xy(x+y)+2(x^2+y^2)-18xy+5(x+y)+2 ] ^{2}+144xy ( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+2) $

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, sums-of-squares

For $x,y \geqslant 0.$ Prove$:$ $$ \left( xy+2\,x+2\,y+1 \right) ^{2} \left( x+y+2 \right) ^{2}\geqslant \frac14
\left[xy(x+y)+2({x}^{2}+{y}^{2})-18\,xy+5(x+y)+2
\right] ^{2}+144\,xy \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+2 \right) \,\,(\ast)$$
First$,$ I checked it by [Wolfram|Alpha: Computational Intelligence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)$,$ and know it's [true](https://tinyurl.com/y3ryfts9).

Morever$,$ it's stronger than [KaiRain's problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h1970813_prove_inequality_with_xy_gt0).

Equality holds when $\{x = 0, y = -2\}, \{x = -2, y = 0\}, \\\{x = 0, y = -\frac12\}, \{x = -\frac12, y = 0\},\\  \{x = 1, y = 3\} , \{x = 3, y = 1\}\,\text{and}\,\{x = 1, y = 1\},$

Now I try to prove it!

Let $S=x+y,\, P=xy.$ The problem can be writen as:

$$ ( P+2\,S+1 ) ^{2} ( S+2 ) ^{2}\geqslant \frac14 ( SP+
2{S}^{2}-22P+5S+2 ) ^{2}+144\cdot \text{P} ( {S}^{2}-2P+2
 ) 
\,\,(\text{1})$$

Or $$\frac{3}{4} ( P{S}^{2}+2{S}^{3}+20PS-71{S}^{2}+228P+52S-172
 ) ^{2}+48 ( 6{S}^{3}-13{S}^{2}+8S-28 ) 
 ( S-4 ) ^{2} \geqslant 0$$
If $ 6{S}^{3}-13{S}^{2}+8S-28  \geqslant 0$ then the inequality is true!

Which means $(\text{1})$ is true when $S\geqslant \frac{1}{18}\sqrt [3]{12997+324\,\sqrt {1609}}+{\frac {25}{18}}{\frac {1}{
\sqrt [3]{12997+324\,\sqrt {1609}}}}+{\frac {13}{18}}\approx 2.4148004292977.$

From here I don't know how to finish this proof.

I hope to see if there is a way to end my proof or another approach and also the *Sum Of Squares* of the inequality $(\ast)$ if if could be.

**Edit.** I found that the inequality $$ \left( xy+2\,x+2\,y+1 \right) ^{2} \left( x+y+2 \right) ^{2}\geqslant k
\left[xy(x+y)+2({x}^{2}+{y}^{2})-18\,xy+5(x+y)+2
\right] ^{2}+144\,xy \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+2 \right) \,\,$$
is true for all $k\leqslant k_0 \approx 0.3074105436.$ Where $k_0$ is a root of ${X}^{3}+{\frac {151}{150}}\,{X}^{2}+{\frac {13}{240}}\,X-{\frac {169}
{1200}}=0$

Who can prove this also$?$

Comment: Maybe @nguyenhuyen_ag can give simpler SOS.

Comment: @RiverLi can you prove my stronger inequality in edit? I can't not, I only check by Maple, it's true.

Comment: It seems not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made most of the work!

I like another substitutions and I'll end you work in the $uvw$'s substitutions.

Let $x+y=2u$ and $xy=v^2$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$(u^2+10u+57)v^4+2(4u^3-71u^2+26u-43)v^2+(4u+1)(u+1)^2\geq0,$$
which is true for $$(4u^3-71u^2+26u-43)^2-(u^2+10u+57)(4u+1)(u+1)^2\leq0$$ or
$$64(u-2)^2(12u^3-13u^2+4u-7)\geq0.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove our inequality for $$12u^3-13u^2+4u-7\leq0,$$ which gives  $$0\leq u\leq1.2...$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$v^2\leq\frac{-4u^3+71u^2-26u+43-8(2-u)\sqrt{7-4u+13u^2-12u^3}}{u^2+10u+57}$$
and since by AM-GM $v^2\leq u^2$, it's enough to prove that
$$u^2\leq\frac{-4u^3+71u^2-26u+43-8(2-u)\sqrt{7-4u+13u^2-12u^3}}{u^2+10u+57}$$ or
$$43-26u+14u^2-14u^3-u^4\geq8(2-u)\sqrt{7-4u+13u^2-12u^3}$$ and since $$43-26u+14u^2-14u^3-u^4>0$$ for any $0<u\leq1.2...,$ it's enough to prove that
$$(43-26u+14u^2-14u^3-u^4)^2\geq64(2-u)^2(7-4u+13u^2-12u^3)$$ or
$$(u-1)^2(u^2+10u+57)(u^4+20u^3-30u^2+12u+1)\geq0$$ which is obvious even for any positive value of $u$.

Comment: Thanks. But why it's enough to prove $v^2\leq\frac{-4u^3+71u^2-26u+43-8(2-u)\sqrt{7-4u+13u^2-12u^3}}{u^2+10u+57}$ ?

Comment: Because $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\geq0$ when $x\geq x_1$ or $x\leq x_2$, where $x_1\geq x_2$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you prove my stronger inequality in edit? I can't not, I only check by Maple, it's true.

Answer (score 2):

*Proceeding along your approach*:

If $S \ge \frac{5}{2}$, it is true.

If $0 \le S < \frac{5}{2}$, since $S^2 \ge 4P$, we have
\begin{align}
&P{S}^{2}+2{S}^{3}+20PS-71{S}^{2}+228P+52S-172\\
=\ & (S^2+20S+228)P+2S^3-71S^2+52S-172 \\
\le\ & (S^2+20S+228)\frac{S^2}{4}+2S^3-71S^2+52S-172\\
=\ & \frac{1}{4}S^4+7S^3-14S^2+52S-172 \\
<\ & 0
\end{align}
and thus it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{3}{4} ( \frac{1}{4}S^4+7S^3-14S^2+52S-172
 ) ^{2}+48 ( 6{S}^{3}-13{S}^{2}+8S-28 )
 ( S-4 ) ^{2} \ge 0$$
that is
$$\frac{3}{64}(S^4+40S^3-120S^2+96S+16)(S^2+20S+228)(S-2)^2 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Nice idea. Then we can give SOS for it but ugly.

Comment: @knvy144444 We are looking for simple SOS.

Comment: Yes, did you write an software in Maple about SOS?

Comment: @knvy144444  No, I am not able to do that.

Comment: But how you can get some nice SOS? My tool is very weak. Only work with from $\sum S_a (b-c)^2$

Comment: @knvy144444   nguyenhuyen_ag can do that. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704885/prove-that-sum-mathrmcyc-40a6-53a5b-ge-0

Comment: I only can have SOS for inequality for a very small inequality, but ugly for i high degree. For example https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2224638p16940304

Comment: @knvy144444  Sometimes, the coefficients are huge, see: nguyenhuyen_ag 's comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704885/prove-that-sum-mathrmcyc-40a6-53a5b-ge-0

Comment: Yes, of course. But I don't know how to guess the form of SOS. I use Maple 17 crack, I can get Equation between two expression. Also, some large equations Maple 17 can not solve. Then I stuck here. You can see my test program https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1101515h2197100_sos_comand

Comment: @knvy144444 Your work is very nice.